# Need to run Seam Webservice on Weblogic

Tags: web-services, weblogic, seam, weblogic-10.x

HI,

I am having a webservice running successfully on JBoss App Server. However, when I try deploying the webservice example on Weblogic 10.0 MP1 after making the necessary changes I get the message that "No business interface, component interface or web service endpoint interface found for Session Bean". In the generated EAR file there is no WSDL file created as well.

Is anyone able to deploy Seam Webservice on Weblogic successfully?

Thanks & Regards,
Hamid

Answer (score 0):

Here are some resources that might be helpful:

- From the Seam 2.0.1 GA documentation: [Chapter 27. Seam on BEA's Weblogic](http://docs.jboss.org/seam/2.0.1.GA/reference/en/html/weblogic.html)
- From the Seam 2.1.1 documentation: [Chapter 39. Seam on BEA's Weblogic](http://docs.jboss.org/seam/2.1.2/reference/en-US/html/weblogic.html)
- From the SeamFramework knowledge base: [Running Seam examples with BEA WebLogic](http://seamframework.org/Documentation/RunningSeamExamplesWithBEAWebLogic)
- From the blog In relation to...: [Weblogic 10, Seam, and EJB3](http://relation.to/Bloggers/Weblogic10SeamAndEJB3)
- From the blog In relation to...: [Seam Reference Guide Updated for WebLogic 10.3](http://relation.to/Bloggers/SeamReferenceGuideUpdatedForWebLogic103)

Maybe you could provide more details about the steps you followed, the full stacktrace, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3238621/weblogic-ejb-complianceexception/3508156#3508156) is the answer (you need have a explicity interface)